# Order elements by a data-index value

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I have a container element containing div elements with a data-index value. I want to reorder the elements by the data-index, so they appear as 1, 2 and 3.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-4" data-index="3">Col 3</div>
    <div class="col-md-4" data-index="1">Col 1</div>
    <div class="col-md-4" data-index="2">Col 2</div>
</div>
```

So how can I sort the elements by the data-index value?

Comment: sort in the page it self? How those divs were generated at first hand?

Comment: the elements will be deattached and appended as the site resizes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Array.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function with proper callback:

```js
$(".container div").sort(function(a, b) {
  return $(a).data("index") - $(b).data("index");
}).appendTo(".container");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-4" data-index="3">Col 3</div>
  <div class="col-md-4" data-index="1">Col 1</div>
  <div class="col-md-4" data-index="2">Col 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I am using flexbox to change the order of the divs:

```js
let cols = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".container .col-md-4"));
cols.map((col)=>{
  let index = col.dataset.index;
  col.style.order = index;
})
```

```css
.container{display:flex;flex-direction:column;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-4" data-index="3">Col 3</div>
    <div class="col-md-4" data-index="1">Col 1</div>
    <div class="col-md-4" data-index="2">Col 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's very clever and nothing changes in the DOM

Comment: `.forEach` makes more sense. OP is probably using a CSS framework (bootstrap) so changing box model might create more problems than it solves.

Comment: Nearly 4 years later. This works brilliantly. Solved a multiple flexbox column problem

Answer (score 2):

Use `document.querySelector` to get all the children then use `sort` to sort this collection and iterate through this collection to append the element back to the div

```js
function reorder() {
  let orderedString = '';
  [...document.querySelectorAll('.container div')].sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.dataset.index - b.dataset.index

  }).forEach(function(item) {
    document.querySelector('.container').appendChild(item)
  })

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-4" data-index="3">Col 3</div>
  <div class="col-md-4" data-index="1">Col 1</div>
  <div class="col-md-4" data-index="2">Col 2</div>
</div>
<button onclick="reorder()">Order</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `sort()`, `attr()` and `appendTo()` like the following way:

```js
$('.container div').sort(function(a,b) {
     a = Number($(a).attr('data-index'));
     b = Number($(b).attr('data-index'));
     return a - b;
}).appendTo('.container');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-4" data-index="3">Col 3</div>
    <div class="col-md-4" data-index="1">Col 1</div>
    <div class="col-md-4" data-index="2">Col 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess `sort()` should return `a - b` rather than `a > b`; it is -1, 0 or 1 depending on whether a is less than, equal or grater than b.

Answer (score 0):

Get the divs and sort it with sort() then attach to the parent doc with html()

```
var divList = $(".col-md-4");
divList.sort(function(a, b){
return $(a).data("data-index")-$(b).data("data-index")
});
$(".container").html(divList);
```